# Unable to get proper paginated data using API

Tags: pagination, import.io

Hello I have tried to extract paginated data using import.io. So far I have managed to retrieve JSON data by using Bulk Extract.

But I need it through the API, i.e. the export pane's API which is currently remaining unchanged even if I update the URLs via Bulk Extract.

Here is the url http://www.metalstorm.net/events/new_releases.php
I want to retrieve the new releases table with the album covers

Hoping to get a response soon

Comment: Hi, can you give me one of the links that you are attempting to paginate with? Some websites that do not have a discernible URL pattern cannot be paginated with import.io.

Comment: http://www.metalstorm.net/events/new_releases.php the URL is added to the question

Comment: Hi, I have taken a look at the pagination and it is very clear and you do not need cookies or javascript to paginate with. When you say that you cannot paginate through the API are you referring to the GET request? If you use the below request and enter your API key and User GUID you can easily paginate through the pages of new releases. Just change the page part of the request (?page=8).

Comment: https://api.import.io/store/data/de0bef46-ce7b-4402-b962-42c492f7e9e9/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.metalstorm.net%2Fevents%2Fnew_releases.php?page=8%3F&_user=(YOUR USER ID)&_apikey=(YOUR API KEY)